# Regex: Invalid group specifier name - react native

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, react-native, expo

My regex works in browser but shows an error in react-native expo app (android) development

Regex:

```
/^(?=.{0,20}$)(?![_.0-9])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/
```

error:

```
Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name
no stack
```

How to fix this error, thanks

Comment: Remove `(?<![_.])`. Add `(?!.*[_.]$)` after `^`. Or, `/^(?!.*[_.]$)(?![_.0-9])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]{0,20}$/`

Comment: Did it finally work, or do you need more help?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest converting the `(?<![_.])` lookbehind into a `(?!.*[_.]$)` lookahead and tighten it a bit (since the length can be checked with the consuming pattern part):

```
/^(?!.*[_.]$)(?![_.0-9])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]{0,20}$/
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*[_.]$)` - no `.` or `_` allowed at the end
- `(?![_.0-9])` - no `_`, `.` and digit allowed at the start
- `(?!.*[_.]{2})` - no consecutive `.` or `_` allowed anywhere
- `[a-zA-Z0-9._]{0,20}` - 0 to 20 letters, digits, `.` or `_`
- `$` - end of string.